# ninja: error: ...libmemalloc_intermediates/export_includes', needed by ..., missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android, ninja

I am attempting to build Cardinal (nougat) for Lithium (Xiaomi Mi Mix). I must say first: I have succeeded in some android rom builds before, all LineageOS based. This is one of several attempts at compiling an AOSP based one and, as before, I enconunter immediate problems due to a general mismatch of rom and device/vendor sources. I research as extensively as I can all of them and can fix some, but others are tough to crack for me.

As this one:

```
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: error: '/home/albertoduqe/cardinal/out/target/product/lithium/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmemalloc_intermediates/export_includes', needed by '/home/albertoduqe/cardinal/out/target/product/lithium/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/copybit.msm8996_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
build/core/ninja.mk:151: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/albertoduqe/cardinal'

#### make failed to build some targets (52 seconds) ####
```

I have searched all over StackOverflow, XDA and googlesource for libmemalloc and I can't find much. It is supposed to be some Qcom display LOCAL_MODULE and I find it referenced here, for example: 
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_display/blob/cm-14.1/msm8996/libgralloc/Android.mk

I have those and (I believe) the rest of hardware/qcom (as well as vendor and device/qcom) sources in my local working tree, so I have no idea of what am I missing, if it is a repo that I do not have synced, or a synced one that I should replace for another, or maybe some change in some mk file that's causing the fail.

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you run the lunch command and choose a right one?

Answer (score 0):

Declare LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in the target makefile. This may help.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an more in-depth answer or provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

The module that is providing the library and include files (libmemmalloc, in your case, based on where the integrating module is looking for the export_includes file) needs to set LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS in its Android.mk . If LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS is non-empty, the build process will automatically produce this file, which then allows *other* modules that set LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to read it (these modules will also *write* an `import_includes` file with the list of include paths they want).

It's described here in a couple of different ways depending on what kind of module is exporting the includes: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core

Answer (score 0):

If you are building lineage add this to your device BoarConfig.mk preferably right after architecture flags

`BOARD_USES_QCOM_HARDWARE := true`

this in device.mk

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    gralloc.msm8953 \
    copybit.msm8953 \
    hwcomposer.msm8953 \
    memtrack.msm8953 \
    android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-impl \
    android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service \
    android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-impl \
    android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service \
    android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl \
    android.hardware.memtrack@1.0-impl \
    android.hardware.memtrack@1.0-service \
    libdisplayconfig \
    libqdMetaData.system
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your BoardConfig.mk file

```
#Display
TARGET_USES_GRALLOC1 := true
TARGET_USES_HWC2 := true
```